# Axler Ch. 3F Problem 25: Show that $U=\{v\in V:\phi(v)=0\ \text{for every}\ \phi\in U^0\}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

The following is problem 25 from chapter 3F of the third edition of Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right*

> Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional and $U$ is a subspace of $V$. Show
> that
>
> $$U=\{v\in V:\phi(v)=0\ \text{for every}\ \phi\in U^0\}$$

Here is my attempt at proving this

Let $B=\{v\in V:\phi(v)=0\ \text{for every}\ \phi\in U^0\}$.

Let $v\in B$.

Now suppose, for proof by contradiction, that $v\notin U$.

Let $\phi\in U^0\subseteq V'$.

Define $\phi_1$ as follows

$$\phi_1w=\begin{cases} 1,\ \text{if}\ w=v \\ \phi w,\ \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

Then, $\phi_1\in U^0$ because it maps all vectors in $U$ the same way that $\phi$ does and the latter maps them all to zero.

So we've shown that $\phi_1 v\neq 0$ and $\phi_1\in U^0$ which contradicts our assumption that $v\in B$ (which requires that $\phi_1 v = 0$).

Hence, by proof by contradiction, we can infer that $v\in U$.

Since this reasoning is true for any $v\in B$ then we have $B\subseteq U$.

Next, let's prove that $U\subseteq B$.

Suppose that $v\in U$.

Then, $v\in V$ and by definition of $U^0$ we have that $\phi v=0$ for every $\phi\in U^0$.

Hence $v\in B$ and thus $U\subseteq B$.

Thus, $U=B$.